# How to quick use module from NPM?

Tags: npm

I use NPM to install some modules. However, every time I use it, I go to the folder where the module is and copy that module and then go to the folder I work in and paste it. Is there a way for me to use the modules I have installed more quickly and efficiently?

How to use NPM testing module effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just copy all resources without folder **node_modules** and when you paste in another folder you can just use `npm install` but I'm not sure, try and let me know

Comment: Yes, I usually use that way. But I think, it is not  a good way to use NPM module

Comment: why do you think that?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).